# AttributeError when creating a new user

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 142, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 32, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

When trying to render this view:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.is_active = False
            new_user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = "Activate your DC-Elects account"
            message = render_to_string('registration/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': new_user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(new_user.id)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(new_user),
            })
            new_user.email_user(subject, message)
            return reverse('elections:account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/signup.html',{
        'form': form,
    })
```

The error message is not very descriptive, but the email is sending with the link correctly, so I'm very confused as to why there is an error. How do I prevent this error and render the next view correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Django's view function should return `HttpResponse` object. [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) is just a method which generate url string, not response object, so this line:

```
return reverse('elections:account_activation_sent')
```

raise the error.

If you need redirect use [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut:

```
return redirect('elections:account_activation_sent')
```